# Datetime picker script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I have used datepicker from jQuery in my page and it is working fine:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $( function(){
    $("#startdate").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
    } );

    $( function(){
    $("#enddate").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
    } );
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <form action="" method="post">
  From Date-Time:<br>
  <input type="text" id="startdate" name="startdate" value="">
  <br>
  To Date-Time:<br>
  <input type="text" id="enddate" name="enddate" value="">
</body>
```

Now I want to add Time to it. I have searched & downloaded the same in jQuery "datetimepicker"but unable to make it work.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.datetimepicker.css">
  <script src="jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $( function(){
    $("#startdate").datetimepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
    } );

    $( function(){
    $("#enddate").datetimepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
    } );
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <form action="" method="post">
  From Date-Time:<br>
  <input type="text" id="startdate" name="startdate" value="">
  <br>
  To Date-Time:<br>
  <input type="text" id="enddate" name="enddate" value="">
</body>
```

Can you please advise, what should be the corrective action.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing jquery before importing datetime picker js

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, some improvement ! I can now see the layout/border of the calender/timer. But nothing inside. Its blank

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved after adding "js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.datetimepicker.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
```